# get data from .csv file, analyze, produce output - python3

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am trying to complete an assignment in Python3. It is very similar to the pdf found [here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/PracticeOfComputingUsingPython/05_ListsTuples/Basketball/)

I have a few questions on both the execution of how to get the information I need, and if possible, some code that could move me along. I am new to python. As right now from the code I have, I keep getting the error `"directory not found"` after running a function to try and read the data. I know the `.csv` file should be in the directory where I save it to in WingIDE, but I can't get it to work correctly.

My first question is after getting each line of the .csv file to read from my get_file_list, what is the best way to take each category and throw it into an efficiency equation?

Here is my `get_data_list` function:

```
def get_data_list(filename):
    data_file = open(filename, "r")
    data_list = [ ] 
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))
    return data_list
```

when I run `get_data_list("player_regular_season.csv")` I get the following error:

> builtins.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'player_regular_season.csv'

Comment: Try to specify the full path to the file (don't forget to escape slashes as `\\ ` or use `/` instead). Also you might want to use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: You should add the [homework] tag to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

For the first try, you can put the data file to the same directory with the Python program and launch it from the directory.

Try also a single purpose script to learn how to work with directories. Learn the functions from the standard doc [15.1.5. Files and Directories](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#files-and-directories), namely [os.getcwd()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.getcwd), [os.chdir(path)](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.chdir), and then [10.1. os.path — Common pathname manipulations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.path.html#module-os.path), namely [os.path.isfile(path)](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).

But read also the doc of other functions in the documents to learn what is available.

When knowing how to work with filenames and paths, have a look at the [13.1. csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html). Not to be scared of all the stuff, start from the end -- [13.1.5. Examples](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#examples) of using the csv module.